# How do I pass in a JSON array as a POST parameter in Swift?

Tags: json, swift, nsurlconnection

The API that I use accepts JSON as a POST parameter, but whatever I try - it doesn't seem to accept it.

```
var post2:NSString = "data={\"item_id\":\"19\"}"

var url2:NSURL = NSURL(string: "\(BASE_URL)item/")!

var postData2:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
var postLength2:NSString = String( postData2.length )

println(post2);
var request2:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url2)
request2.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request2.HTTPBody = postData2
request2.setValue(postLength2, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request2.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request2.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request2.setValue("Bearer ABC123", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

var reponseError2: NSError?
var response2: NSURLResponse?

var urlData2: NSData? = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request2, returningResponse:&response, error:&reponseError)

let json2 = JSON(data: urlData2!)
```

The println shows

```
data={"item_id":"9"}
```

and I get a response back from the server, but it seems that I am not passing in proper JSON.

Any ideas what I need to pass in? Seems like it has to be an NSString.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm silly

`var postData2:NSData = post.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!`

should be 

`var postData2:NSData = post2.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!`

problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error do you get?

The JSON is valid.  I'm wondering if your server is expecting `application/json` and not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

If the server is expecting `application/json` then remove "data=" from your body and just send "{"item_id":"9"}".  POST doesn't need to be a key value pair.